# opengl distortion of push-popMatrix

Tags: opengl, matrix, distortion

i have a "normal" opengl scene, and want to overlay this scene with a simple quad.

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glTranslatef(-0.8f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
// draw background
gl.glBegin(GL_QUADS); // of the color cube
gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 1.0f);
gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0, 1.0f);
gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
gl.glVertex3f(0, 0.5f, 1.0f);
gl.glEnd();
gl.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glPopMatrix();
gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

as u can see on the screenshot, the new matrix is distorted. the colored lines are the axes.

[image]
[image]

Now the question: How can i set an aspect ratio (like in gluPerspective) for my matrix to render a correct squad?

Comment: In what way is this distorted? Could you possibly make another diagram where you draw out what it is supposed to look like, or highlight the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to account for the size and shape of the viewport. Transformations are done in "normalized coordinates". This means that the bottom left corner of the viewport is (0,0) and the top right corner of the viewport is (1,1). Your projection matrix needs to account for the shape of the viewport to compensate and make your quad square.

The ratio of the height and width of a viewport is known as the "aspect ratio".

See [this page](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/opengl-perspective-projection-matrix/), the important section for your problem is *The field of view and Image Aspect Ratio*. There's too much content to post a usable excerpt here. You should have no trouble finding resources on projection matrix aspect ratios, and how to compute a correct projection matrix.

Comment: thanks for the site. i dont get it, i read many of these articles. but i dont understand how to set this "aspect ratio" too my current matrix ... seems i have to read a lot more :/

Comment: @Ontje Get the size of the viewport, `width / height` is the aspect ratio. Use that number for the aspect ratio. Does that help?

Comment: i know how to calculate the ratio, i already used it for the main scene. and it seems to work as the grid is perfect. after pushMatrix... this distortion comes up

Comment: just found out sth. to fix the issue, added in the new matrix:              `final float aspect = (float) getWidth() / getHeight();
  gl.glScalef(1.0f, aspect, 0.0f);`... doesnt know if this is the correct way.. it works... but why???

Comment: Why what? Why do you have to do that? Because the transformations output device coordinates (in the range 0 to 1 from one edge to the other, both horizontally and vertically), as I described in my answer, so opengl stretches/squashes the output into the viewport shape. The scale factor you added counteracts that and makes 1 in the horizontal direction the same distance as 1 in the vertical direction. Google "normalized device coordinates" for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: dont know why i didnt get it yesterday. thought about it, now it is totally clear. is this the correct/best way to get the "aspect ratio" into the new matrix? thanks alot!

Comment: If you are only setting up a 2D projection, then the scale is all you need. If you are setting up a projection matrix for 3D perspective, then you need to setup near/far range, and a field of view. In that case you would need to construct a perspective matrix.